# What would cause a queue to be visible from other machines, but not the machine it was created on?

Tags: msmq

I created a public queue on Machine1 I can write to the queue (from asp.net) from Machine2. When I deploy the code to Machine1, I get the error:

Queue does not exist: Machine1\MyQueue.

Comment: Why are you using public queues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally you could check to see if the user which your IIS app pool is running under has permissions to write onto the local queue.

Comment: Why would a public queue need permissions explicitly?

Comment: Even when I gave full control to the user running the site... still no luck. Created a private queue.. works fine now. Makes no sense.

Comment: I have never had to use public queues.

Answer (score 0):

I expect main cause would be Machine 1 isn't in the same Active Directory forest as Machine 2.

What line of code raises the error message?

Cheers
John Breakwell